# Error with 'group by' from joined tables in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, inner-join

I have two tables, Table1 with `City_Code, name, population`, and Table2 with `City_Code, Type`.
I need to sum the population by city type, so I use this code:

```
SELECT SUM(population) FROM Table1 
JOIN Table2 ON Table2.City_Code = Table1.City_Code
GROUP BY Table2.Type
```

The resulting table looks like this

[image: result]

There are indeed 6 city "Type"s, and the sum is correct, but the figures don't match. I've checked the data with `sumif` in excel, and the real sum by is actually this:

[image: Excel]

why is the SQL result not in the correct population for type

Comment: The numbers are the same in your two images. Only the ordering is different. Add `Table2.Type` to the `SELECT` list.

Comment: It was _that_ simple eh? thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no error on your query since it is outputting result. It just that the order of the result is different from you expected result. Try this,

```
SELECT  Table2.Type, SUM(population) TotalPopulation 
FROM    Table1 JOIN Table2 ON Table2.City_Code = Table1.City_Code
GROUP   BY Table2.Type
ORDER   BY Table2.Type
```